# How to hide all directories from <TAB> completition in bash

Tags: bash, tabs, hide, directory

I would like to show only the set of the allowed commands in the restricted shell from  completition .

Comment: $FIGNORE can work for you

Comment: I would like to hide all directories and files. What is the content of the FIGNORE in this case?

Answer (score 0):

`export FIGNORE=\~`

This ignores directories.  I am not sure how to do it for all files.

Comment: It is now working: <br/> 
$ export FIGNORE=\~ <br/> 
$ / <br/> 

home/       lib64/      mnt/        proc/       selinux/     <br/> tftpboot/   var/
bin/        dev/       lost+found/ opt/        root/        <br/> srv/        tmp/        webapps/
boot/       etc/       lib/        media/      persist/      <br/>sbin/       sys/        usr/